# .NET 6: Map settings from appsettings.json file to class object

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project which references a class library. I am trying to register some dependencies from within class library. One of the dependency I am trying to register is using options pattern to map settings from `appsettings.json` file to strong typed class.

Web API `Program.cs` class:

```
builder.Services.RegisterInfrastrcuture(builder.Configuration);
```

Extension method in class library:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class InfrastrcutureInjector
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterInfrastrcuture(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<DBConfig>(configuration.GetSection(nameof(DBConfig))); //Compilation error
    
        return services;
    }
}
```

I get this compilation error:

> Cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection' to 'System.Action<TPFoundation.Infrastructure.Models.DBConfig>'
> on code:
>
> services.Configure(configuration.GetSection(nameof(DBConfig)));

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
services.Configure<DBConfig>(options => configuration.GetSection(nameof(DBConfig)).Bind(options));
```

Comment: Getting the compilation error on .Bind(options)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
services.Configure<DBConfig>(configuration);
```

Comment: Getting the compilation error on configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the Microsoft documentation and found out that I was missing the following NuGet package:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

According to [Microsoft Options Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options-library-authors) documentation, the above package is required by the overloaded version:

```
Configure<TOptions>(IServiceCollection, IConfiguration)
```